# Script not parsing cells when called in another Sub , excel Vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that runs through a column in a sheet called data and parses the cell length to cut down the length. This script works when placed in a module and run on the sheet. However the issue I am having is that when I call it in my overall script. Does anyone have an idea why it is being run but not working?

This is the Sub

```
Sub Remove10()
Dim i As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    If Len(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 11).Value) > 8 Then Cells(i, 11).Value = Right(Cells(i, 11), 8)

Next i
End Sub
```

And this is where it is called

```
Private Sub RunFullAutomation_Click()
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'This is the action that is taken when the "GO!" Button is pressed.
'Runs the following three subs in order without further need for user input.
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Get the data and set up the sheets
Call GetAndSetUpData
Call Remove10
Call RemoveYearsBefore18

Call RemoveYearsBefore16
'Data fixing
Call removeCancelledDescrepency
'report generation
Call FindExceptions
'Notify the user that the automation is all done
Range("CurrentTask").Value = "Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: In the first sub, you are referencing explicitly `ThisWorkbook` and then implicitly `ActiveWorkbook` and active sheet (in `Cells(i, 11).Value = Right(Cells(i, 11), 8)`. In the second Sub you are implicitly referencing the active workbook and sheet. It is best to be always explicit, and it might be a good idea to pass the workbook (or even the worksheet) as sub parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the probably the most common VBA error in StackOveflow (from experience):

```
Sub Remove10()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lr
        If Len(ws.Cells(i, 11)) > 8 Then ws.Cells(i, 11).Value = Right(ws.Cells(i, 11), 8)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The problem is that if you do not refer to the explicit `Worksheet` of the `Cell` it uses the `ActiveSheet`. Thus, if the `Range()` gets broken, trying to get cells from different cells.